# Continuous functions, Urysohn lemma

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space. If $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ are continuous functions and $\gamma_1(1)=\gamma_2(0)$, show that
 $$\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X, \gamma(t)= \begin{cases} \gamma_1(2t) &\mbox{ if } t \in[0,\frac{1}{2})  \\ \gamma_2(2t-1) &\mbox{ if } t\in(\frac{1}{2},1] \end{cases}$$

is continuous.

I think this has something to do with the Urysohn lemma, because $[0,1]$ is compact and Hausdorff, but I'm not sure how this could help me.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Urysohn. It's trivial from the definition of "continuous".

Answer (score 1):

It's the pasting lemma you need: We have two continuous functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined on closed subsets $C_1$ and $C_2$ of a space $X$, such that $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for all $x \in C_1 \cap C_2$. Then $f$, the combination function, is continuous on $C = C_1 \cup C_2$. Here $C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $C_2 = [\frac{1}{2},1]$. No need for compactness etc.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838497/4280), e.g.

Comment: Thank you! I've got one question left. In this case, $C_2=(\frac{1}{2},1]$, an half open interval. I know this is locally compact, but not closed.. So does the pasting lemma still 'work' then?

Comment: No $C_2$ is $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. Which is closed. On the intersection, $\frac{1}{2}$, you should check that the two functions coincide.  Then the lemma applies.

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks again!